# Laravel add two directories to local disk

Tags: php, laravel

Filesystem.php
How can i add another directory to local disk.
Currently only having the images directory

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('images/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify the root of each disk defined in `config/filesystems.php`. You are free to define as many disks as needed however:

```
'images-subdir' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('images/subdir'),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you need:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php